# Create pdf file in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

string s="
                 
                    Name
                    nnnn
                 
                 
                    Age
                    dd

```
             </tr>
          </table>"
```

I need to convert this string to a pdf file.Can anybody help me for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iTextSharp - Introducing Tables](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables)

The .NET framework does not contain any native way to work with PDF files. So, if you want to generate or work with PDF files as part of your ASP.NET web application, you will have to rely on one of the many third party components that are available. Google will help you to find one that fits your budget, as well as a range of open-source free components. One of the free components is iTextSharp, which is a port of a well known Java utility, iText.

Tables will probably be one of the most used elements in PDFs generated from ASP.NET applications to provide the structure for documents such as orders and invoices.
This overview is not an exhaustive examination of tables, but provides an introduction to working with them through iTextSharp

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option is:

http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx

One thing to note, for completeness, is that it's not obvious how to "complete" pdf forms...

This link:

[PDFSharp.Net Filling Form Fields on an existing PDF](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=894&hilit=fill%20field)

Has that imporant tidbit squirreled away...  search for starscream74's post & amirtofighi's follow-up for the details/sample.