# Generate PDF file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to make pdf ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575584/how-to-make-pdf)
>   [Create pdf file in Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252872/create-pdf-file-in-asp-net)

What is the best way to generate pdf files in asp.net using C#? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/.

iTextSharp is a PDF library that allows you to CREATE, ADAPT, INSPECT and MAINTAIN documents in the Portable Document Format (PDF)

Answer (score 1):

I use a 3rd party piece of software called ABCPDF, it seem fine to me, but there are lots of other options.

Here's an open source one that might suit yuor needs:

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/open-source-pdf-library-for-aspnet-pdfsharp/

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Report Server is good, if you are generating reports from a database (and you have access to SSRS, of course)