# asp.net C# generate pdf files

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate PDF file in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119561/generate-pdf-file-in-asp-net)

Whats is a good and easy-to-use library (Third party software) in order to create a fillable pdf file? Im using asp.net C# and basically I want to generate a fillable pdf file that I send it to other users so they can fill it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119561/generate-pdf-file-in-asp-net/6119575#6119575

Answer (score 0):

Aspose for PDF .NET is a good one.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx

iTextSharp is good too.

http://itextpdf.com/

Can't think of a good open source offering that is full featured however.

Answer (score 0):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is a popular open source library to create PDF documents. It supports creating forms in PDF documents and filling them programmatically.

Comment: iTextSharp isn't true open source, specific commercial applications require the purchase of a license.

Answer (score 0):

TallPDF.NET also is very good and feature-rich.

http://www.tallcomponents.com/default.aspx?id=tallpdf3-features